# jquery image slider auto play and click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Please suggest any change where i need to make in this code in order to make this slider auto play after 4000 milliseconds.right not it is working fine on click.i made few changes after following few suggestions but its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {    
var Page = (function() {    
var $navArrows = $( '#nav-arrows' ),
$nav = $( '#nav-dots > span' ),
slitslider = $( '#slider' ).slitslider( {
onBeforeChange : function( slide, pos ) {

$nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
$nav.eq( pos ).addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );    
}
} ),    
init = function() {    
initEvents();    
},
initEvents = function() {    
// add navigation events
$navArrows.children( ':last' ).on( 'click', function() {    
slitslider.next();
return false;    
} );    
$navArrows.children( ':first' ).on( 'click', function() {    
slitslider.previous();
return false;    
} );
$nav.each( function( i ) {    
$( this ).on( 'click', function( event ) {    
    var $dot = $( this );    
    if( !slitslider.isActive() ) {    
            $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
            $dot.addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );    
    }    
    slitslider.jump( i + 1 );
    return false;    
} );    
} );    
};    
return { init : init };    
})();    
Page.init();    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the [slitslider docs](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/05/fullscreen-slit-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/) I think you need to add these two lines to the following excerpt of your code:

```
.slitslider({

    // slideshow on / off
    autoplay : true,
    // time between transitions
    interval : 4000,

    onBeforeChange : function(slide, pos) {
    $nav.removeClass('nav-dot-current');
    $nav.eq(pos).addClass('nav-dot-current');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain how interval is being used in program? i am not seeing variable which is using this. or it is a keyword? Sorry i novice in jquery

Comment: In this case it is a keyword, or parameter, to the slitslider object. There is a javascript function called setInterval(somefunction(), time_delay) which can be used to run your own javascript code in an interval, but slitslider should take care of that for you just by adding the 'interval' and 'autoplay' parameters as shown above.  (not sure if this answers your question?)